# handling Command+H programmatically in Mac OS

Tags: java, macos, javafx

I have a JavaFX application that i have ported to Mac. When the application in foreground Command+H suppose to hide the application but for my ported application it is showing version details in a new popup windows.

I wanted to check if my program is suppose to handle Command+H and then hide the application or should it be handled by OS.

Comment: I have no experience with Java, but in standard AppKit the functionality to hide an application is achieved by sending the `hide:` message to the shared `NSApplication` object.

Comment: Both ⌘H (hide application) and ⌥⌘H (hide others) should be handled for you automatically in the `java` menu by default; ⇧⌘? is a common alternative for application help.

Answer (score 1):

On macOS, it was solved by the following.

```java
//
// Disable default popup window.
//
Desktop.getDesktop().setAboutHandler(null);

//
// Hides the stage when Command + H is pressed.
//
scene.getAccelerators().put(
    new KeyCodeCombination(KeyCode.H, KeyCombination.META_DOWN), () -> {
        primaryStage.setIconified(true);
    }
);
```